# NSTableView Alternating Row Colors Draw Incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a view based NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController.  I have set the NSTableView to use alternating row colors.  When the table is empty it displays the alternating row colors appropriately.  However when the table is populated the row after the last draws with the wrong color (See screenshot).  Am I doing something wrong to cause this or is this a common bug?

[image: NSTableView with incorrectly drawn alternating row color]

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: What's `-numberOfRowsInTableView:` ? Any chance there's a gray row with 0 height?

Comment: Or that the last white row has an odd height?

Comment: Guys there really is no code as it is all done with bindings.  I have model objects in an NSArrayController.  The NSOutlineView is bound to the NSArrayController.  There is no datasource so -numberOfRowsInTableView: does not apply.

Comment: Is it that the last item has whitespace (\n or something) at end?

Comment: I don't think there is an extra row with height 0 for the following reasons.  First there are only 3 items in my NSTreeController.  Second, when I use the arrow keys to move between items I cannot move any lower than the 3rd item in the list.  Third, I am not implementing the delegate method –outlineView:heightOfRowByItem: and in Interface Builder I have set the row height on the NSOutlineView to be "fixed" at 38 pixels.

Comment: I'm having a similar Problem with my NSTableView (viewBased) bound via code to an arrayController. This artifact only gets drawn, when there are uneven entries. But not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a blue row but with height is 0

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to code your table (no big effort needed), then you would have a better chance to know what's going on and to fix your bug.